# Java I/O classes and performance

Tags: java, file

Reading Thinking in Java 4th ed. I've got some doubts about I/O operations performance:
I've read that it's better to "wrap" InputStream objects in BufferedInputStream, but in my mind I can't see any difference. Isn't i.e. file operations already buffered? What's the advantages of file buffered write?

Comment: Hmm this is what I've thought at first. But if InputStream reads a byte, the wrap class BufferedInputStream should call InputStream.read <buffer size> times from wrapped InputStream resulting in <buffer size> accesses to disk, isnt it?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the `InputStream` API. It has three methods named `read`. Two of these methods allow bulk operations (on `byte[]` arrays). Internally, `BufferedInputStream` keeps a `byte[]` array as its buffer. It will fill its buffer using the other `InputStream`'s bulk methods, minimizing the number of calls. Therefore, if you're reading a 500-byte file and `BufferedInputStream` is buffering 100 bytes, the other `InputStream`'s bulk `read` method will be called 5 times.

Comment: @Adam Paynter: Ok. That's the point. Doesn't It have the same behavior to read a 500-byte file with 5 calls to InputStream.read(byte[100]) or with BufferedInputStream(InputStream, 100) which make 5 calls to InputStream.read(byte[100])?

Comment: If `BufferedInputStream` is, in fact, buffering 100 bytes then you are correct, there is no difference. It can offer advantages if you *want* to consume bytes in chunks smaller than 100-at-a-time. You can theoretically consume that 500-byte file one byte at a time, but the `BufferedInputStreamStream` will make sure only 5 system calls are made.

Comment: Well ok... As the author constantly repeated that wrapping to BufferedInputStream is always the right choice I thought it would to do some special optimization. Thanks for replies, see you again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system's IO buffering is on a different level than the Buffered*putStream.

Each call on `FileOutputStream.write(...)` induces a native method call (which is typically more costly than a java-internal call), and then a context switch to the OS' kernel to do the actual writing. Even if the kernel (or the file system driver or the harddisk controller or the harddisk itself) is doing more buffering, these costs will occur.

By wrapping a BufferedOutputStream around this, we will call the native write method only much less often, thus allowing much higher throughput.

(The same is valid for other types of IO, of course, I just used FileOutputStream as an example.)

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't i.e. file operations already buffered?

Maybe, maybe not - depending on the OS, the HD used, the way of access (e.g. reading big consecutive blocks vs randomly accessing small blocks all over the place), etc. In the worst case, adding a BufferedInputStream probably won't harm performance noticeably. In the best case, it can improve it by magnitudes (replacing many little file accesses by one big read/write).

Comment: +1: Most operating systems take care of the bulk of the buffering for you. This probably results in the system calls incurring the largest hit.

Comment: Probably true, but it is also true the programmer knows a lot more about the use case than the OS does. For example, the program will read 2MB consecutively. Your own 2MB buffer is a lot bigger than anything the OS is doing, and at that level, you save time on the physical I/O too.

Answer (score 2):

An `InputStream` will only request as much data as you request, so if you request 1000 characters one character at a time, that will turn out to be 1000 seperate disk accesses, which will become pretty slow.

A `BufferedInputStream` however will request data from the `InputStream` in larger chunks, thus reducing the need for seperate disk accesses.

The same goes for output, instead of writing every character seperately, there are fewer physical disk writes with a `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: FYI: On most operating systems, requesting n characters individually will not result in n disk accesses.

Comment: Ah ok, just wanted to make it as n chars = n accesses to demonstrate the usefulness of the Buffered version.